# workqueues in device driver development?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

now i am dealing with the device driver coding. As the part of development, need to explore with the workqueues and work_struct.

i got only few reference for this.

html">http://www.hackchina.com/en/r/119579/jiq.c_html

The above link shows a c code jiq.c . From this not getting much idea about how the calls are flowing inside the driver code. I want to get a good idea about **workqueues** and **work_struct** .
Can anyone suggest some documents ?.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few I could get hold of -

1. You can start of [here](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-7-sect-6).
2. This is about the [workqueue interface in Kernel 2.6](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6916) by Robert Love
3. This one from [IBM Developer Works](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tasklets/index.html) explains tasklets in addition to work queues and has sample examples!

Comment: thanks for your help....loaded my first wqdriver successfully using the help of simple work queue example from the given link. planning to get more about workqueue.

Comment: Thats nice to hear! :) Do ask if you need anything more specific. And do accept the answer when you are done with! :)

Comment: one doubt: For my wqdriver i followed the  third link that you given above. The init_module prints "hi" and cleanup_module prints "bye". The problem was when inserting my driver i can see the log "hi" but can't see "bye" while removing the module. After that if i tried to load the module then "bye" message appeared followed by  "hi". why this happening ?